# How to calculate the centroids in k-means++ by using distances?

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means, apache-commons-math

I am using the k-means++ clusterer from Apache Commons Math in a interactive genetic algorithm to reduce the number of individuals that are evaluated by the user.

Commons Math makes it very easy to use. The user only needs to implement the 
[`Clusterable`](http://commons.apache.org/math/api-2.1/org/apache/commons/math/stat/clustering/Clusterable.html) interface. It has two methods:

`double distanceFrom(T p)` which is quite clear and `T  centroidOf(Collection<T> p)`, which lets the user pick the centroid of a cluster.

If used on euclidean points, the centroid is very easy to calculate. But on chromosomes it is quite difficult, because their meaning is not always clear.

My question: Is there a efficient generic way to pick the centroid, not depending on the problem domain? (E.g. by using the distance)

---

EDIT

Ok, here is now my code for the centroid calculation. 
The idea: The point that has the lowest total distance to all other points is the nearest to the centroid.

```
public T centroidOf(Collection<T> c) {
  double minDist = Double.MAX_VALUE;
  T minP = null;

  // iterate through c
  final Iterator<T> it = c.iterator();
  while (it.hasNext()) {
    // test every point p1
    final T p1 = it.next();
    double totalDist = 0d;
    for (final T p2 : c) {
      // sum up the distance to all points p2 | p2!=p1
      if (p2 != p1) {
        totalDist += p1.distanceFrom(p2);
      }
    }

    // if the current distance is lower that the min, take it as new min
    if (totalDist < minDist) {
      minDist = totalDist;
      minP = p1;
    }
  }
  return minP;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*k-means* requires an averaging metric (e.g., Euclidean). Without defining such a metric and space, you don't even know whether the average of points is actually a point inside the space.

You could, however, use [k-medoids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids), which considers only the original points as candidates for medoids (while k-means finds means/centroids which are not necessarily on the original points). The algorithm looks for points which minimize pairwise dissimilarities (i.e., `distanceFrom`).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I want to use a point of the population as centroid without creating new points. But I also want to use this implementation. The only question is how to implement the `centroidOf()` method? At the moment I am selecting a point of the collection randomly.

Comment: There is an algorithm in the link.

Comment: I accept the answer because of your link. The desired implementation is now shown in the original question.